# PPTX to TeX converter

Tags: beamer, powerpoint

is there a converter available to generate tex code out of powerpoint slides? 
beamer documentcalls is preferred. another tex code is accepted if beamer output would not possible. is there maybe an open source project available to modify the converter?

Comment: VBA code provided in [any-way-of-converting-ppt-or-odf-to-beamer-or-org](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66007/any-way-of-converting-ppt-or-odf-to-beamer-or-org) worked for me with ppt. I don't know with pptx.

Comment: thx. i am not familiar with vba but it will be read.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, could you leave a comment as to why? It's not an unreasonable question, although it has been asked already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a project (amongst others), but it will not do all of the conversion stuff.

[Creating scientific slideshows: see RTFBeamer](http://www.unc.edu/~monogan/computing/latex/)

Anyway, maybe you have to convert your pptx to ppt.

Apart from that: Writing Beamer code without generation will be better.

A similar thread exists:

[Any way of converting ppt or odf to beamer or org?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66007/any-way-of-converting-ppt-or-odf-to-beamer-or-org)

Comment: see the revision graph - a rollback was made to my impaired grammar. yes. subsequent, this grammar was removed due to another part of a sentence which reflects my research (ppt / pptx ->  tex) better. anyway, it would be an alternative to edit the sentence without a rollback. no need to get into panic.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough your comment is not helpful but the answer by mnemonic was helpful :-)

Comment: @user29701 Absolutely - I've deleted it